# How to create the "last" rule in Drools retracting the event if no other rules fire?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

I have two rules: one generates the alert message and appending it to the list of strings attribute of event (there will be multiple such rules in future), and the other one retracts event if no alerts was generated.

I use `salience` for setting the rules priority (the "last" rule should fire literally last). But the rules order is wrong for some reasons so the alerts list is still empty and all the events are retracted. Please look at my samples below.

**MainHello.scala**

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
import org.kie.api.KieServices
import org.kie.api.builder.Message
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory

object MainHello {

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val events = List(
    new Event(123L, null, null),
    new Event(456L, null, null),
    new Event(789L, null, null),
    new Event(688723L, null, null),
    new Event(12L, null, null),
    new Event(13L, null, null))


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val kieService = KieServices.get()
    val repository = kieService.getRepository
    val kfs = kieService.newKieFileSystem

    kfs.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("hello.drl", this.getClass))

    val kb = kieService.newKieBuilder(kfs)

    kb.buildAll

    if (kb.getResults.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults.toString)
    }

    val kContainer = kieService.newKieContainer(repository.getDefaultReleaseId)
    val session = kContainer.newKieSession()

    events.foreach { item =>
      println("INPUT OBJECT: " + write(item))
      val facthandle = session.insert(item)
      session.fireAllRules()
      println("result object:  " + write(session.getObject(facthandle)))
    }

  }
}
```

**Event.java**

```scala
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Event implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private java.lang.Long event_id;
    private java.lang.String alert;
    private java.util.List<java.lang.String> alerts;

    public Event() {
    }

    public java.lang.Long getEvent_id() {
        return this.event_id;
    }

    public void setEvent_id(java.lang.Long event_id) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
    }

    public java.lang.String getAlert() {
        return this.alert;
    }

    public void setAlert(java.lang.String alert) {
        if (alerts == null) {
            alerts = new java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>();
        }
        alerts.add(alert);
        this.alert = alert;
    }

    public java.util.List<java.lang.String> getAlerts() {
        return this.alerts;
    }

    public void setAlerts(java.util.List<java.lang.String> alerts) {
        this.alerts = alerts;
    }

    public Event(java.lang.Long event_id, java.lang.String alert,
                 java.util.List<java.lang.String> alerts) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
        this.alert = alert;
        this.alerts = alerts;
    }

}
```

**Hello.drl**

```
rule "alert"
when
  e: ru.test.Event(event_id == 123)
then
  modify(e) {
    setAlert("alert")
  }
end

rule "Retract" salience -1
when
  e: ru.test.Event (alerts == null || alerts.empty == true)
then
  retract(e);
end
```

**console output**

```
INPUT OBJECT: {"event_id":12,"alert":null,"alerts":null}
result object:  null
INPUT OBJECT: {"event_id":13,"alert":null,"alerts":null}
result object:  null
INPUT OBJECT: {"event_id":123,"alert":null,"alerts":null}  // This object should not be retracted because "123" event_id generates alert
result object:  null
```

As you can see, all the events become `null`.

Drools version is `7.8.0.Final`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand this part: "... the alerts list is still empty and all the events are retracted.". Isn't exactly that what the last rule is doing? Retracting events whose alerts list is empty?

Comment: Yes but even events with non-empty alerts list are retracted. I tried to replace the retract with setting some flag and I see events with BOTH alerts list filled and flag set. Looks like the retract rule is executed before all the others, when the alerts list is still empty at every rule.

Comment: Could you include in the question the code you are using to insert the events into the session and to fire the rules? And which version of Drools are you using?

Comment: Done, sir. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to see if you can come up with a self-contained test demonstrating your problem. I've done a simple POC and it is working as expected for me.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Sir, apologies for the late reply, I have added the full code sample.